# !pip install ktrain errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, ktrain

I am trying to install the `ktrain` package in Python (Using Jupyter Notebook) and I get a huge set of errors every time. I am on a Windows 10 laptop (if that contributes).

As of now, my code in jupyter has only had one line:

`!pip install ktrain`

I have Python 3.9 installed from python.org and run Jupyter using Anaconda (which uses Python 3.8), and I tried the following in command prompt:

`pip install ktrain`

`pip3 install ktrain`

and the following in anaconda prompt:

`conda install ktrain`

The one in anaconda prompt says

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - ktrain
```

And the ones in command prompt give the error shown in the following link:

https://www.codepile.net/pile/MN8kgG5W.

Note: *I used this link for showing it since the message is too big and increases the number of characters in this post beyond the given limit.*

How do I resolve it. Because using `import ktrain` says that:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-ccbda6fc29a3> in <module>
----> 1 import ktrain

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ktrain'
```

Also, just to clarify, I have NumPy installed since `pip install numpy` in cmd gives:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\parvj\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (1.19.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is the case already, but it worked on Google Colaboratory.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the [ktrain installation instructions for Windows](https://github.com/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-do-i-install-ktrain-on-a-windows-machine) in the ktrain FAQ, which says you need to install the Visual C++ redistributable.

This is also described in [this post](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12016#issuecomment-555354320).

Comment: I followed the instructions, and still no luck.

Comment: The error you posted indicates that you're not using the installed Conda distribution, as specified in the FAQ instructions.  Take a look at the Python path in the error message.